# Working of map vs applymap in pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am newbie to data science and I am bit confused about working of `map` and `applymap` in pandas. As when I executed code `df.applymap(lambda f: f*2)` and `df.apply(lambda f: f*2)` provided same result. But when I change code for both which were `df.applymap(lambda f: f*2 if f < 7 else f)` and `df.apply(lambda f: f*2 if f < 7 else f)` then apply method caused an error. Upon my understanding, I came to conclusion that `applymap` works for each **scalar value** where `apply` does not work for each scalar value but instead it executes operation for whole **column or series**.
Kindly veterans help me out here if I am correct or not. Thanks in advance

Note: df in code refers to whole DataFrame not series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `apply` works on a row or a column basis of a DataFrame, `applymap` works element-wise on a DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you Ashok. That's what I thought. Much appreciated.